# My code crashes when a specific combination of values is generated

Tags: python, pygame, typeerror

So I've been working on my first game using pygame and I created a function to create enemies. There is some logic on how they created - there must always be a free lane left so total number of enemies mustn't be higher than 3. There are several random choices and it has being crashing when a certain combination of values are randomly generated.

My function:

```
#cretating and manipulating enemies
def enemy_actions(enemies):

    free_lanes = 0
    free_lane_positions = []
    new_enemies_lanes = []



    #going through all lanes
    for i in lanes:
        lane_taken = i[1]   


        if not lane_taken:

            #counting how many free lanes there are
            free_lanes = free_lanes + 1

            #adding free lane position to a list
            free_lane_positions.append(i[0])

    print("Number of free lanes " + str(free_lanes))







    #if atleast 2 lanes are free then we randomly select how many new enemies we will add
    if free_lanes > 1:



        #randomly selecting how many enemies will be added
        number_of_enemies = random.randint(1,len(free_lane_positions) - 1)
        print("Number of enemies " + str(number_of_enemies))


        #repeating action for the number of enemies required
        for i in range(number_of_enemies):

            #randomly selecting lanes for enemies
            lane_x = random.choice(free_lane_positions)


            #adding it to the list of taken lanes
            new_enemies_lanes.append(lane_x)



            #removing taken up lane from list of free lanes
            free_lane_positions.remove(lane_x)

            #marking lane_x as taken in lanes
            for i in lanes:
                if i[0] == lane_x:
                    i.remove(False)
                    i.append(True)

        #(self, place, x, y, length, width, path, speed):
        #building enemy 
        for i in new_enemies_lanes:
            Enemy = enemy(screen, i, enemy_y_start, 60, 60, enemy_path, random.randint(3,8))
            enemies.append(Enemy)
```

When the values

```
Number of free lanes 4
Number of enemies 1
Number of free lanes 3
Number of enemies 1
Number of free lanes 2
Number of enemies 1
```

happen to be generated over several cycles the game crashes with an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Pygame.py", line 225, in <module>
    enemy_actions(enemies)
  File "Pygame.py", line 136, in enemy_actions
    Enemy = enemy(screen, i, enemy_y_start, 60, 60, enemy_path, random.randint(3,8))
TypeError: 'enemy' object is not callable
```

I don't understand how that case is different from any other combination. Please tell me if extra code is needed.

Thanks!

Comment: It's telling you `'enemy' object is not callable` but nowhere if your code can we see what `enemy` actually is — that makes it pretty hard to help.

Comment: what is `enemy()` ? Maybe it should be `Enemy()` or something different. There is good rule to use `UpperCaseName` for classes - `class Enemy:` - and `lower_case_names` for variables/instances - `enemy_instance = Enemy()`

Comment: We need **all** the relevant code. Please see: [mcve]. It also looks like there is some refactoring to be done. I can give it a try tomorrow (if we have enough code, obviously).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is caused by the fix in your previous question: [I received a name error when trying to call a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59013177/i-received-a-name-error-when-trying-to-call-a-method).
It seems that you're class names a lower case and the variable names are have upper case capital letters. 
`enemy` is the name of a class, but in the `for` loop it is used for a variable:

> ```py
> for enemy in enemies:
>    enemy.Load()
> ```

The class object is replaced and the instruction

> ```py
> Enemy = enemy(...)
> ```

causes an error

Do not use the name `enemy` for variables, to solve the issue:

```py
for Enemy in enemies:
    Enemy.Load()
```

Note, in general the names of classes have upper case capital letters and variables respectively instances are lower case. The fact that you do it the other way around round causes some confusion and misunderstanding by the readers of your questions.

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't know that was the wrong way round. I'll use thee correct way next time I create classes. Thanks for help!

Comment: @EugeneLevinson Technically it is not wrong. But it is against the recommended [Naming Conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions).

Comment: Ye, I know what you mean, the only reason I did it this way is that a while back I saw a tutorial on classes which had it that way round so I assumed that was the recommended way.